# Different colors for scatter plots based on origin of data

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot, data-science

I have a LIST called 'samples', I am loading several images into this LIST from 2 different folders, let's say Folder1 and Folder2. Then I convert this list to a DataFrame and plot them in a 2D scatter plot. I want the scatter plot to show all contents from Folder1 to be Red color and all contents from Folder2 to be in blue color. How can I accomplish this. My code is below:

```
    samples = []
    Folder1 = glob.iglob('/home/..../Folder1/*.png')
    Folder2 = glob.iglob('/home/..../Folder2/*.png')

    for fname in Folder1:
        img = misc.imread(fname)
        samples.append((img[::2, ::2] / 255.0).reshape(-1))

    for fname in Folder2:
        img = misc.imread(fname)
        samples.append((img[::2, ::2] / 255.0).reshape(-1))

    samples = pd.DataFrame(samples)

    def do_ISO(df):
        from sklearn import manifold
        iso = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=6, n_components=3)
        iso.fit(df)
        A = iso.transform(df)
        return A

    def Plot2D(T, title, x, y):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_title(title)
        ax.set_xlabel('Component: {0}'.format(x))
        ax.set_ylabel('Component: {0}'.format(y))
        x_size = (max(T[:,x]) - min(T[:,x])) * 0.08
        y_size = (max(T[:,y]) - min(T[:,y])) * 0.08
        ax.scatter(T[:,x],T[:,y], marker='.',alpha=0.7)

    Plot2D(do_ISO(samples), 'ISO_Chart', 0, 1)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to say without seeing the arrays you are working with. You are actually plotting the result of your `do_ISO()` function, which creates an array using `sklearn.manifold.Isomap.transform()`.

Does this function preserves the ordering of your elements in you array?
If so, things could be fairly easy. As you are first filling all the images from Folder1 and then from Folder2, you could simply count the number of items in Folder1, and split your array in 2 based on that number (eg. `nbFilesFolder1`). then you do 2 calls to `scatter`:

```
ax.scatter(T[:nbFilesFolder1,x],T[:nbFilesFolder1,y], marker='.',alpha=0.7, c='red')
ax.scatter(T[nbFilesFolder1:,x],T[nbFilesFolder1:,y], marker='.',alpha=0.7, c='blue')
```

Comment: Diziet Asahi you just nailed it. This is exactly what I wanted. Yes so the Folder1 contains 72 items then Folder2 contains 12 items. And I used your technique to plot them by splitting the array and it worked exactly the way I wanted. Thank you very much and I really appreciate it. It's you guys that motivate new and young data analyst like me to keeping going.